# How to type Sigma and Product in PDFLatex

Tags: unicode, minted, unicode-math

I want to be able to type the unicode characters of Σ and Π in latex. Specifically, I want to be able to include these into my latex code and have them rendered appropriately on the corresponding pdf. I can't seem to figure this out on my Mac with M1 chip.

Here's an example that I want to make work:

```
\documentclass[12pt,A4]{article}
\usepackage[outputdir=build,cache=false]{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{lean}{
It would be nice to type Σ Π in Pdf latex on my M1 Mac with Mac OSX Monterey since I want to use Lean with minted.
}\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

Right now I run pdflatex from the terminal like this:

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode
```

Maybe there is some equivalent for xetex?

Comment: Which engine do you use? This should work with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX (as long as `minted` doesn't do anything strange, I haven't tested).

Comment: Can you help me switch "pdflatex -synctex=1 -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode ???.tex" to an XeLaTeX equivalent?

Comment: just change `pdflatex` to `xelatex`.

Comment: that no longer compiles for me. Is there a way that uses pdflatex instead?

Comment: I just want those two and maybe one other unicode character. Is there some library?

Comment: Should've read your question more thoroughly, you stated that you're using pdfLaTeX. Sorry for the inconvenience this may have caused. See @egreg's answer for a solution.

Comment: Oh no worries. I didn't take it that way. A lot of people would have gone with the solution you proposed I just figured it wasn't the best for my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load `textgreek`.

Note that `A4` is not a valid option (should be `a4paper`) and that you should not use braces around the material inside `minted`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{lean}
It would be nice to type Σ Π in Pdf latex on my M1 Mac
with Mac OSX Monterey since I want to use Lean with minted.
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

[image]